# SyntaxError: JSON.parse data don't like 0?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, multipartform-data

Can someone explain to me why I get the below error by executing the following code?

> SyntaxError : JSON.parse : unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

After thousands of trials, I realized that if I replace the value `0` from `StatutForm` with `2` or anything else, the error disappears. `FormData` does not accept the value `0`?

Thank you for your help.

The code :

```
$(document).on('click', '.button1, .button2', function() {
    var Form_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("IDForm", $('#IDForm' + Form_id).val());
    formData.append("FirstnameForm", $('#FirstnameForm' + Form_id).val());
    formData.append("NameForm", $('#NameForm' + Form_id).val());
    formData.append("BirthForm", $('#BirthForm' + Form_id).val());
    formData.append("EmailForm", $('#EmailForm' + Form_id).val());
    formData.append("SchoolForm", $('#SchoolForm' + Form_id).val());
    formData.append("DateFromForm", $('#DateFromForm' + Form_id).val());
    formData.append("DateToForm", $('#DateToForm' + Form_id).val());
    formData.append("DaysForm", $('#DaysForm' + Form_id).val());
    formData.append("TodayForm", $('#TodayForm' + Form_id).val());

    if (!$(this).hasClass('button1')) {
        formData.append("StatutForm", "1");
    }
    else {
        var texte_Form = $('#ecrire_' + Form_id).val();
        var mail_Form = new Blob([texte_Form], { type: "text/xml"});
        formData.append("mail_Form", texte_Form);
        formData.append("StatutForm", "0");
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', 
        url: 'file.php', 
        dataType: "json", 
        data: formData, 
        cache: false, 
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (form) {
            alert("Right !.");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Error !");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The error message sounds like that the sever returns an empty response. It's impossible to tell what's wrong without seeing the sever side code.

Answer (score 0):

You receive an error when parsing data received from the server.

> dataType: "json"

dataType – The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.

json – Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/